How to change admonition block syntax?
In the Myst documentation, ::: is used to create admonition blocks like this:
:::{tip}

VSCode can't read Myst with MysT-Markdown

:::


Result:

But it seems VSCode is unable to parse that correctly. However, ``` works fine. Here's the same result using that:

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I've tried finding any options in th VSCode settings, but to no avail.
